# Network Connectivity & Virtual Network Adapters

Tags: networking, connection, virtual-network

Whenever I'm connected to any Virtual Network adapter (Hamachi/Tunngle/Evolve), my connection begins to randomly drop every 30 seconds or so, then it reconnects instantly. When I'm browsing the web, I get an error message saying that my network has changed, and after a couple of seconds it redirects me to the desired webpage.
I can't play any games nor even communicate in Skype properly.
I was thinking about setting the priority of my adapters and moving the Virtual Network adapter higher in the ladder, however this is impossible in Windows 10 as far as I know.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you are considering nic priorities so that you can control which traffic goes over the vNic? if so, make sure your vnic isn't stealing the default gateway. In Cisco client that feature is called Split tunneling, and it only transfers traffic destined for a network known to be on the other side of the tunnel onto the vnic, and sends everything else (web or whatever) out whatever nic the default gateway route indicates (your physical nic mostly).

Comment: I'm sorry but I find it hard to understand what you meant. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.